# Macro in an expression is not working as expected

Tags: c++, macros

I have a simple macro to add 2 variables, which is not working as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ADD(x,y) (x+y);

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1;
    int c = ADD(a,b)+1; //c=11 - NOT EXPECTED
    int c = 1+ADD(a,b); //c=12 - EXPECTED

    cout<< c;
}
```

In the above code, when I add 1 at the beginning of the macro, it's giving the expected output. But if I add 1 at the end it is not actually adding 1.

Why is it having this behavior?
As per my knowledge, when a macro is used, compiler will just replace the macro with the token string during compilation. If it is so, in both the cases, the output should be same.

First case: `c = (a+b)+1`
Second case `c = 1+(a+b)`

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the macro.  Also remove the macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the macro and write it like

```
#define ADD(x,y) (( x ) + ( y ))
```

Otherwise for example this line

```
int c = ADD(a,b)+1;
```

is equivalent to

```
int c = (a + b); +1;
```

that is it contains a declaration of the variable `c` and the statement

```
+1;
```

with no effect.

Comment: Better, remove the macro.  `1 + 1` is a lot clearer than `ADD(1, 1)`.

Comment: yeah, I agree a+b is lot clearer than macro. Here I am just trying to understand the behaviour of macros. Hence this simple code.